# merging two dictionaries with two separate values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

```
dict1 = {a:10, b:15, c:20}
dict2 = {a:25, b:30, c:35}
```

what I would like output to be is:

```
dict3 = {a : (10, 25), b : (15, 30), c : (20, 35)}
```

Heres a sample of what I have

```
dict1 = {'192.168.1.21':23,'127.0.0.1':5,'12.12.12.12':5,'55.55.55.55':10}
dict2 = {'192.168.1.21':27,'10.10.0.1':7,'127.0.0.1':1}
dict3 = {}

for dictionary in (dict1,dict2):
  for k,v in dictionary.iteritems():
    dict3[k] = dict3.get(k, 0) + v
```

Can anyone help me with this

Comment: I'm sure many people will be glad to help you when you show what you've tried so far.

Comment: This can be done easily, but I question why it needs to be done at all. If the keys are the same, both dictionaries must have been generated from the same source, so why not also generate `dict3` at the same time instead of joining them later?

Comment: Your original example isn't that good a simplification of what's apparently your real case.  What do you want `dict3["10.10.0.1"]` to be?  `(7,)` or `(None, 7,)` or something else: maybe `(0, 7,)`?

Comment: These were taken from a .txt file more specifically a tcpdump. I am trying to calculate how many time the source IP address appears compared to how many times the destination IP appears for the same ip address

Comment: @DSM (0,7,) would be ideal

Comment: Currently you are adding the values, shouldn't you store them in a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, try writing:

```
for k in set(dict1.keys())|set(dict2.keys()):
    dict3[k] = (dict1.get(k,0),dict2.get(k,0))
```

This will take all the keys from both dictionaries and return their values as tuples, just like you want. It returns zero if the key doesn't exist for one of the lists, but you can change this to whatever you might need.

So for:

```
dict1 = {'192.168.1.21':23,'127.0.0.1':5,'12.12.12.12':5,'55.55.55.55':10}
dict2 = {'192.168.1.21':27,'10.10.0.1':7,'127.0.0.1':1}
```

It will return:

```
dict3 = {'55.55.55.55': (10, 0), '10.10.0.1': (0, 7), '12.12.12.12': (5, 0), 
         '127.0.0.1': (5, 1), '192.168.1.21': (23, 27)}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, this worked perfectly. 2 weeks into learning python, I quite enjoy it.

Answer (score 1):

I might do something like:

```
>>> dict1 = {'192.168.1.21':23,'127.0.0.1':5,'12.12.12.12':5,'55.55.55.55':10}
>>> dict2 = {'192.168.1.21':27,'10.10.0.1':7,'127.0.0.1':1}
>>> ds = dict1, dict2
>>> {k: tuple(d.get(k, 0) for d in ds) for k in set().union(*ds)}
{'55.55.55.55': (10, 0), '10.10.0.1': (0, 7), '12.12.12.12': (5, 0), 
'127.0.0.1': (5, 1), '192.168.1.21': (23, 27)}
```

This uses a few tricks.  `set().union(*ds)` gets the union of all the keys in the dictionaries:

```
>>> set().union(*ds)
set(['55.55.55.55', '10.10.0.1', '12.12.12.12', '192.168.1.21', '127.0.0.1'])
```

(Hat-tip to @JonClements.  I used to have to write `set.union(*(map(set, ds)))` and I never liked the duplication of `set`.)

`tuple(d.get(k, 0) for d in ds)` makes a tuple from either `0` or the value associated with the key `k` in each dictionary.

And the whole thing is wrapped up in a dictionary comprehension so we don't need any other loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
for dictionary in (dict1,dict2):
  for k,v in dictionary.iteritems():
    dict3[k] = dict3.get(k, 0) + v
```

Here you are adding the values from 0, resulting in a single value. You wanted a tuple, so for this approach to work you would need to start from an empty tuple and add a single-item tuple of the new value:

```
dict3[k] = dict3.get(k, ()) + (v,)
```

What I don't like about this approach is that you are iterating over all the items of both dictionaries, completely defeating the purpose of using dictionaries (looking up specific items quickly by key). If `dict1` has at least all the keys in `dict2`, I would do this:

```
dict3 = dict((key, (value1, dict2.get(key, 0))) for key, value1 in dict1.iteritems())
```

This would combine all the matching keys and insert 0 for each key in dict1 that does not exist in dict2. However, if `dict2` also has keys that `dict1` does not, the only way to make sure you get all of them is to iterate both dictionaries. Of course, it's possible that you only care about the keys of `dict1` (i.e. you don't need to see destination IPs for which there is no matching source IP), in which case this is exactly what you want.

Comment: thanks this also answered another question of mine. It also helps me to be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

```
#You can use has_key() dictionary built in function# 

for k,v in dict1.items()
       if dict2.has_key(k):
              dict3[k]=(v,dict2[k])
```